# Old and beaten ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified and java Locale.setDefault()

Tags: java, oracle, locale, ora-12705

I have a question that makes me crazy
on my laptop i have oracle-xe 10.2.0 on ubuntu

DB Charset : AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

//    Default locale before overwriting is ru_RU
//    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("EN"));
//
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "test", "test");
    try {
    // @machineName:port:SID, userid, password

      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      try {
        ResultSet rset = stmt
            .executeQuery("select * from test");
        try {
          while (rset.next())
            System.out.println(rset.getString(1)); // Print col 1
        } finally {
          try {
            rset.close();
          } catch (Exception ignore) {
          }
        }
      } finally {
        try {
          stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
      }
    } finally {
      try {
        conn.close();
      } catch (Exception ignore) {
      }
    }
  }
```

If i comment Locale.setDefault i have an ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified exception (default locale in this case stays ru_RU), but if i set default locale to EN, then everything is all right.

What can it mean? Why it is used Locale.getDefault value instead of NLS_LANG, like has written in every article about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please use these VM Options:
-Duser.region=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US

Answer (score 0):

By default JDBC locale is determined from the JVM locale, NLS_LANG is ignored. Another way to change locale is specifying -Duser.language and -Duser.country command line arguments.